# Mysql server gone away 2006 - not working with CRON & ajax only

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron, mysql-error-2006

we are push notification providers and using GCM to deliver push notifications. but from last few days we are facing issues **"Mysql server gone away 2006"** , we have tried everything like Max_execution_time, MAX_PACKET_ALLOWED.. etc server variable. also we have added **set_time_limit(0)** to head of cron.

Server Environment:

```
CENTOS:6 
RAM : 96 GB
CPU: 20 Core
DATABASE: MYsql
PHP: 5.6
Framework: Codeigniter
```

also using **pconnect** False for Codeigniter database connection. 
Main problem in when we are accessing database using direct function call its working fine. but when are using threw the **cron** (PHP SCRIPT) or **ajax** its giving **mysql server gone error** . may be its causes we are calling multiple function in cron in line but the call is **synchronous** means second function dependent of result of first function. at last we are sending push to Google.

Comment: You should move this question to [https://dba.stackexchange.com/](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). You'll get better help there.

Comment: You're missing all the steps you have done to try to solve / fix this, since you say "everything".

Comment: I have written what i tried to solve. please help if you something about it